# Linkedlist Node in C+

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am learning a book on data structures, and complied their node in linked list example, and I receive this error:

```
 and Everything.cpp|7|error: expected unqualified-id before "int"|
 and Everything.cpp|7|error: expected `)' before "int"|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

The code for the node is:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node(int data)    //Compile suggest problem is here
    {
        this-> data = data;
        previous = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    }
    int data;
    struct Node* previous;
    struct Node* next;
} NODE;
```

I am not familiar with structs and I am using Code::blocks to compile. Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I trust the author of this data structures book with C++. There's no need to use "struct Node*" ("Node*" will do), or to typedef Node as NODE. It can't have been done for compatibility with C, because the struct has a constructor. Odd. Perhaps it's very old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code sample is wrong.  There should not be the keyword `struct` in front of the constructor declaration.  It should be:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    Node(int data)  // No 'struct' here
    {
        this-> data = data;
        previous = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    }
    int data;
    struct Node* previous;
    struct Node* next;
} NODE;
```